# Java: Запись данных в БД

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Сделал метод, который записывает данные в БД.

Данные уже заполнены, а как сделать, чтобы они вводились с клавиатуры при вызове метода?

```
void nameProvider() throws SQLException {
    statement.execute(
        "insert into provider.infortaionaboutprovider (city, mail_adress, bank_detals, rating) values (\"Polsk\", \"mailardess@mail.ru\", 22222, 1)");
}
```

Comment: добавьте описание statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
  try {
    // create a mysql database connection
    String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";

    String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    Class.forName(myDriver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

    // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.sql.Date startDate = new 
    java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

    // the mysql insert statement
    String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, 
    is_admin, num_points)"  + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.setString (1, "Barney");
    preparedStmt.setString (2, "Rubble");
    preparedStmt.setDate   (3, startDate);
    preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, false);
    preparedStmt.setInt    (5, 5000);

    // execute the preparedstatement
    preparedStmt.execute();

    conn.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.err.println("Got an exception!");
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Почитай тут: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement

Comment: preparedStmt.setString (1, "Barney");
    preparedStmt.setString (2, "Rubble");
    preparedStmt.setDate   (3, startDate);
    preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, false);
    preparedStmt.setInt    (5, 5000); тут происходит ввод информации и ввод в коде , для одного объекта ввести не проблема, а если их 100? поэтому я и хочу написать метод, который добавляет в бд. вызвал --> ввел данные --> записал. еще один объект - вызвал снова

Answer (score 0):

Если количество и порядок вводимых данных известен и не меняется, то будет правильным написать метод который принимает эти самые данные и обрабатывает.

Для обработки данных введенных с клавиатуры в реальном времени, в случае работы с консолем, легче использовать `System.in` предварительно обернув в `java.util.Scanner`

```
    private void foo(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("City: ");
            String city = scanner.next();

            System.out.print("Email: ");
            String email = scanner.next();

            System.out.print("BankDetails: ");
            String details = scanner.next();

            System.out.print("Rating: ");
            int rating = scanner.nextInt();

            save(city, email, details, rating);

            System.out.println("\nHit 'q' to quit...");
        } while(!scanner.next().trim().equals("q"));
    }

    private void save(String city, String email, String bankDetails, int rating) {
        String sql = "insert into provider.infortaionaboutprovider (" +
                     "city, mail_adress, bank_detals, rating) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setString(1, city);
            statement.setString(2, email);
            statement.setString(3, bankDetails);
            statement.setInt(4, rating);
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```